# Keeping track of the head node in Linked List in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}node;

node * display(node * head)
{
    node * tmp = head;
    printf("%d\n", tmp->data);
    tmp = tmp->next;
    printf("%d\n", tmp->data);
}

node * create()
{
    // create nodes
    node * head = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    // assign tmp to the head of the node
    node *tmp = NULL;
    tmp = head;

    // place data into head node
    head->data = 2;
    printf("%d\n", head->data);

    // move to next null and create space, then insert data
    head = head->next;
    head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->data = 5;
    printf("%d\n", head->data);

    display(tmp);
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{   
    create();

    return 0;
}
```

With this code, I'm trying to create a simple linked list, and pass the `head` pointer to a function called `display`. However, when I run the program, the numbers printed are "2" and "159088" instead of just "2" and "5". How should I be passing and keeping track of the `head` pointer?

Comment: You declare `display` to return `node *`, but you don't return anything. That will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: As for your problem, when you do `head = head->next;`, ***where is `head->next` pointing?*** I suggest you try to draw a list on paper, using small squares for the nodes and arrows for the links. Then do your operations on paper, changing or draw new arrows. Do the operations you do in your program make sense if you draw it?

Comment: Should I point head->next = NULL before I move to it? When I do that, it gives the same outcome as well.

Comment: Though technically, here, it's not undefined as the value isn't used by the caller, it's still a latent bug.

Comment: The function `create()` is supposed to return a `node *` but doesn't return anything.  That's going to be a problem as there's no way to access the newly allocated node from outside the function — so you have a major memory leak, regardless of other problems.  You should probably start over with a fresh empty source file.

Comment: That's a good start. Then consider what's happening when you do `head = head->next`. Or the next `head = malloc(sizeof(node))`. If you had an integer variable `a` (as in `int a;`) and did the assignment `a = 5;`. Then you follow that with `a = 10;`. What would the contents of `a` be then? It's really no difference with pointers, an assignment will *overwrite* the value of the destination (`head` in your case), making you lose the original value.

Comment: When I create space at the head of the list, I insert '2' into head->data. After, create a block of NULL at head->next, and "move" to the NULL slot, then create space and insert '5' into the new data slot
EDIT
I should also point the next head->next to NULL to show the end of the linked list

Comment: `head =NULL` doesn't create anything.  `node* tmp = NULL` only declares space to store the memory address of a node, it doesn't actually create a node.  You do create a node in memory with `malloc` below; _that_s what creates space, not setting anything to NULL.  Make sure you understand that difference to get the most out of your question.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: there are LOTS of examples on StackOverFlow for linked lists.  Suggest performing a search of StackOverFlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're failing to actually *link* your list.  You never point `head->next` to the node you alloc for the second value.  Try a change like this:

```
// create next node, then insert data
head->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
head = head->next; 
head->data = 5; 
printf("%d\n", head->data);
```

you should carefully read all the comments you've received as well; though you haven't hit them yet there are a few more bugs in your code, mostly with missing function returns and uninitialized data.

Note also that the real power of linked lists is you don't need to know their length ahead of time.  Adding 2 values, then printing 2 values, is well and good, but you should be using a loop to iterate through the *entire* list to print it, following each link to the next node until you get to a `null`.

From your comments in the code and on the question, I can see that you have a faulty understanding of `NULL`.  `NULL` isn't an empty place, it's an *unset pointer*.  A pointer set to `NULL` explicitly has no value, not an empty value.  You say,  "move to next null and create space, then insert data" but what you should be doing is, "allocate the next node, *storing its address* in `head->next`, and set its data".

Comment: I see my issue. when attempting to move to the next block in the linked list, I was initially moving to nothing and creating space at nothing, resulting in nothing.

Comment: Not exactly.  I tried to edit my answer to help correct that misunderstanding, but what you're saying isn't quite right .  Take another read at my edits.  I guess I'd say you were creating space in memory (`malloc`) but not retaining the address that was returned, so your second value was lost in a memory leak.  Since `head->next` never actually gets set to a valid value, I suppose it's an uninitialized pointer and can have any value, including 159088

Comment: That makes sense. By nothing, I meant I was moving to a location that didn't contain any reference, resulting in a breakage of the link (from memory leak?). I should always create and make sure there is a specific slot in memory to be able to move to before attempting to move.

Regarding the return values, I should either have made the functions 'void *create()' and 'void *display(node *head)' or returned one of the structs I created such as 'head' or 'tmp'

Comment: yeah, and when you create new nodes, set their `next` pointer to NULL.  Then test whether it's null when you're iterating through the list to know when you're at the end of the list.

Comment: Should I be declaring my functions as node * create() or just simply node create()?
Also, should I be declaring them as void * create() or just simply void create()?

Comment: Also, how come I am not able to declare head->next = NULL, head = head->next, head = malloc(sizeof(node));? It will only let me declare the next as NULL, then create space through malloc, and only then move to head = head->next

Comment: Choosing a function return value is part of programming and it depends on what you're trying to do.  Please read this to get some ideas about pointers that will help you decide whether to use `node` or `node*`, or `void`, or `void*`. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm   Note that `void` is a placeholder for _no_ return value, while `void*` is a pointer to data without a type specified.  `void*` is what you'd use instead of `int` if you wanted to be able to store arbitrary elements in your list.  Read the link!  Understand it!  You'll see what I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177913/discussion-between-dan-farrell-and-ancd3ea4).